# PHP profiling - getting very different durations for same pieces of code

Tags: php, time, profiling

I am using `microtime(true)` to measure how long it takes for my PHP code to run, and i am getting strange results.

Sometimes it takes 1 centisecond, sometimes it takes 2, it looks completly random. I am always doing the same thing in that code (defining some constants and building a HTML page out of objects)

1. there are no random parts
2. No disk access (except for the file includes)
3. no session access, no db access, and
4. also no other programs than the os's programs running at the same time.

What could this be due to ? How accurate is the microtime function ?

Comment: How often did you do this? There are many influences that might change the measured time.

Comment: There are too many reasons to list for execution time to vary slightly over time. Also, if you're only displaying "centiseconds" without decimals, the difference between 1.9999 centiseconds and 2.0000 centiseconds would appear to be 1.

Comment: If your code runs longer than one timeslice (even when your computer is "idle" it will be switching tasks regularly) you'll get that effect, that's why you should run the code x times and calculate an average.  Have a look at [Ning's microbenchmarking framework](http://www.ning.com/code/2010/05/php-microbenchmarking/) for some inspiration.

Comment: I'm displaying the result on the page which i refreshed many times (yes i'm using end - start). The result is sometimes 0.0124.... and sometimes 0.0253... I'm not converting values into integers.
I'll try to run it several times.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using it properly?

microtime() does not return the amount of time it took to execute the script.

Here's an example from php.net to calculate script execution time.

```
<?php
$time_start = microtime(true);

// Sleep for a while
usleep(100);

$time_end = microtime(true);
$time = $time_end - $time_start;

echo "Did nothing in $time seconds\n";
?>
```

Comment: Yes i'm using it this way.